# CSS Float left style behavior with only flex layout and changing the order

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve a column and row layout in CSS flex only for sections. I know there are other approaches possible, but I am trying to learn CSS flex layout and find its limitations. I have a number of sections below each other in html like this:

```
<div id="main">
<section id="section1">Section1</section>
<section id="section2">Section2</section>
<section id="section3">Section3</section>
<section id="section4">
<h1>Section4</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dignissim tortor dictum quam consequat hendrerit. Aliquam nisl nisi, faucibus sed elit a, mollis scelerisque dui. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse sodales semper augue, quis sagittis lacus dapibus ut. Vestibulum fringilla ut leo quis consequat. Suspendisse potenti. Sed vel purus velit. Phasellus condimentum non turpis id consectetur. Vivamus non leo id elit sodales tincidunt. Mauris pretium massa ac lacus varius convallis. Morbi sit amet justo sed mi ultricies iaculis. Ut malesuada justo quis magna fermentum ullamcorper. Vivamus quis leo turpis. Aenean at mauris ac ex tincidunt aliquet. Sed iaculis vestibulum pretium.
</p><p>
Sed quis pharetra tellus. Integer nec ante sodales massa dictum consectetur et nec eros. Fusce et nisi orci. Vivamus ornare eget eros et posuere. Phasellus et semper nunc, sed cursus purus. Maecenas vulputate sem eros, a porta velit accumsan eu. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Aenean commodo blandit efficitur. Maecenas imperdiet in erat eu pretium. Proin dapibus massa ac dui maximus imperdiet. Sed eget maximus leo.
</p>
</section>
</div>
```

And in a JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t5zmv1wj/5/

I want to change the layout of those sections without changing the html structure or order of the sections. With only css I am trying to layout the flex boxes to have one box to the side as a column  and then the rest of the boxes below each other next to it. This is what I am trying to achieve:
[image: desired layout]
I got close, but only have section1 next to section 4, while sections 2 and 3 are below section 4, instead of next to section 4 and below section 1 like this [image: actual layout]
Here are two examples in js fiddle of what I am trying to achieve, but both require changing the html structure to work, which I don't want to do:

- https://jsfiddle.net/9d5tja3r/
- https://jsfiddle.net/yqtz26pr/1/

Comment: This is a job for CSS grid not flexbox. Don't try to hack it with flexbox, you will end with a hacky code and headaches

Comment: Cool, thanks. You can make that an answer I would accept if you want..

Answer (score 0):

@Temani Afif came with the right suggestion: use css grid. That was exactly the answer I needed. This is a js fiddle showing how to achieve it easily. https://jsfiddle.net/2zm3oa86/2/. With the html below, the following css styles things nicely:

```css
body, html, #top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#top {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #4444FF;
}
#top > aside {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}
#main {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template: auto auto auto auto / 20% calc(80% - 20px);
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #99AACC;
  
}
#main > section{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red; 
}
#main > section#section4 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 4;
}
```

It still uses a flexbox for the aside, which I like to keep it separate from the grid layout, and works easily. The grid sets a template, with 4 rows, each with auto heights, and 2 columns, of 20% and 80% (almost, minus grid gap) width. The #section4 is places specifically in row 1/column 1, and spans 4 rows. The other sections are then auto-paced in the remaining rows. By having 4 rows (instead of 3), the sections 1-3 just take uip the space necessary for their content, and the remaining space is given to the (empty) row 4).

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="top">
<aside>
  Aside
</aside>
<div id="main">
<section id="section1">Section1</section>
<section id="section2">Section2</section>
<section id="section3">Section3</section>
<section id="section4">
<h1>Section4</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dignissim tortor dictum quam consequat hendrerit. Aliquam nisl nisi, faucibus sed elit a, mollis scelerisque dui. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse sodales semper augue, quis sagittis lacus dapibus ut. Vestibulum fringilla ut leo quis consequat. Suspendisse potenti. Sed vel purus velit. Phasellus condimentum non turpis id consectetur. Vivamus non leo id elit sodales tincidunt. Mauris pretium massa ac lacus varius convallis. Morbi sit amet justo sed mi ultricies iaculis. Ut malesuada justo quis magna fermentum ullamcorper. Vivamus quis leo turpis. Aenean at mauris ac ex tincidunt aliquet. Sed iaculis vestibulum pretium.
</p><p>
Sed quis pharetra tellus. Integer nec ante sodales massa dictum consectetur et nec eros. Fusce et nisi orci. Vivamus ornare eget eros et posuere. Phasellus et semper nunc, sed cursus purus. Maecenas vulputate sem eros, a porta velit accumsan eu. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Aenean commodo blandit efficitur. Maecenas imperdiet in erat eu pretium. Proin dapibus massa ac dui maximus imperdiet. Sed eget maximus leo.
</p>
</section>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```